# How to generate samples for different uniform distributions given first-two moment matrix

Tags: matlab, random, correlation, uniform

Consider a concrete example, I have three different uniform distributions, i.e., x~U(-40,20),y~(-20,40),z~(-20,20). 
So I can calculate E[x+], E[x-], E[y+],E[y-],E[z+],E[z-], where x+ denotes max{0,x}, x- denotes min{0,x}.

Based on the uniform distribution, the moment matrix is calculated by 
E[(x+,x-,y+,y-,z+,z-)^T(x+,x-,y+,y-,z+,z-)]. At the same time, I restrict E[x+x-]=0 in the moment matrix.
For simplicity, assume x,y,z are i.i.d

My question is how to randomly generate samples (x+,x-,y+,y-,z+,z-) under my setting given the first-two moment in matlab or R? 
I have searched a lot and found no method existed to solve the problem I am facing.

Appreciate for all of your help or suggestion on this look-simple question.

Relevant link for generate multivariate uniform distribution is referred to : http://comisef.wikidot.com/tutorial:correlateduniformvariates
But it cannot solve my problem because it only considers all variates following the same specific uniform distribution.

Comment: This question is rather mathematical. Therefore, you may obtain a better answer at https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Or rather https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, Luis Mendo.